# JWT Signature with Request Body

Tags: jwt

I wanna create a Restful API using JWT with signature. The API only allows post method and there is request body in Json format. How do I add request Json body in JWT Signature?

```
https://localhost/Booking/Submit
JWT
.header {.alg="RS256"}
.payload { sender="ABC", recipient="XYZ", timestamp="010102020101010"}
.Signature {...}

Request Json body
{ "BookingId"=1, "BookingDate"="0404202001010", "BookedByName"="Mr. John", "BookedByContact"="12345678", "FacilitiyId"="10021"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JWT token is conventionally base64 encoded. This value is then added to your URL request as a header value for the “Authorization” key.

Your JSON payload is posted in the same URL request, except it makes up the body this time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my question is how can I include JSON body in the JWT signature. Typical JWT signature only contains header (ie alg) and payload (ie, sender, recipient and timestamp in my above example) of JWT.

Comment: Why don't you just try adding it into the payload? You're just adding additional custom claims (e.g. ...`="010102020101010", BookingId=1, ...`). I am noticing that your keys aren't in quotes, so maybe you're using some framework/lib/dependency that has preset keys. In that case, you might want to refer to whatever documentation is associated. Just look for something that mentions custom claims. BTW, happy new year!

Comment: Sorry for delay. As understood, JWT authorization header is only used for security purpose which means basically claims are security related information or requester details.